# Introductory phrases and restrictive clauses

Tags: commas, clauses, relative-pronouns

Do I need to put a comma after an introductory phrase inside a restrictive clause?

Example:

She realized that because Paul took the money, he was an accessory to her crime.

She realized that because Paul took the money he was an accessory to her crime.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 1):

Or even

> She realized that, because Paul took the money, he was an accessory to
>   her crime.

all three are accepted.  The trend is towards lighter punctuation. And since there is no confusion in a short sentence like this, choose no comma.

That is the current trend. The current principle is to read the sentence out loud and listen for the punctuation. Punctuate as you phrase.

Comment: That's likely the best choice, because it separates the clauses where the intonation would do it in speech. If the speaker wishes, of course, they can punctuate it any way at all; there are no real rules for comma usage in English.